# Is There any Way to Create A Child Window That Has the Same Properties as the Parent?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, javafx

I know that in swing you could open a child window/dialog/frame with a parent, and that the children windows would have kind of the same properties as the parent, such as sharing the emblem in the top left. Is there any kind of feature like that in JavaFX 8? This creates a new window, but doesn't have any parent that shares information(is even able to close parent and child doesn't close):

```
@FXML
private void onNewClanCreation(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ClanCreationPanel.fxml"));
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.setTitle("New Clan Creation");
    stage.show();
    }
```

NOTE: I've read both [JavaFX 2.0 FXML Child Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349877/javafx-2-0-fxml-child-windows) and [JavaFX open new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041760/javafx-open-new-window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you show your Stage initialize it's owner:

- [`stage.initOwner(parentStage);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initOwner-javafx.stage.Window-)

Comment: Would: `stage.initOwner(((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());` work?