# How Can I Call Stage.initOwner() From a MenuItem On Action Method?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I just came from [Is There any Way to Create A Child Window That Has the Same Properties as the Parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851450/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-child-window-that-has-the-same-properties-as-the-pa) and I tried to call `stage.initOwner(((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());` but it didn't work and I got an exception. I don't think that I'm using this correctly. How should I attempt to call this from the onAction method?

ORIGINAL CODE BLOCK:

```
@FXML
private void onNewClanCreation(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ClanCreationPanel.fxml"));
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
stage.initOwner(((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
stage.setResizable(false);
stage.setTitle("New Clan Creation");
stage.show();
}
```

Exception:

```
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.MenuItem cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Node at com.gmail.physicistsarah.program.core.ControlPanelController.onNewClanCreation(ControlPanelController.java:65)
... 54 more`
```

EDIT: Added stage.initOwner

Comment: Hi Sarah, please post the exception that you are getting. Also the code fragment provided doesn't contain stage.initOwner ?

Comment: @Jurgen Just made the edits.

Comment: The problem of the error is in your stacktrace, you can convert a `MenuItem` to `Node` as it is not extended from the same. You need a `Node` to get the `Window` from it !

Comment: Itachi meant: you CANNOT covert MenuItem to Node ....

Answer (score 2):

This worked:
`stage.initOwner(this.nameLabel.getScene().getWindow());` Thanks @ItachiUchiha