# Does any of javafx extra libs have a such component?

Tags: java, javafx, splitpane

I need a split panel with minimaze feature.
Maybe, some extra javafx libs implement this component or It would better to create it by myself?

For example what I want Eclipse've already had:

[image]
->
[image]

Comment: Possible [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17673292/230513).

Comment: very interesting thanks, but not exactly what I need

Comment: I think you have to implement that by your self. This is a complex layouting task. So make your thoughts about that hole Layouting thing here.