# Overlapping elements in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

How can I have two javafx UI elements (e.g. Panes) overlap such that the one in focus is in the foreground?

I have tried using stack panes, but I'm not able to move elements inside a stackpane.

EDIT: I imagine it like this:

Example

[image: Example]

Obviously, these are Ubuntu windows. I would like to have this overlapping behaviour within a javafx scene and not with multiple stages.

Comment: In JavaFX, children are rendered in the order they appear in the parent's children list (not counting `Node.viewOrder`). To bring a node to the foreground, modify the list appropriately; for convenience, the `Node` class has the `toFront()` and `toBack()` methods. If using Java 9+ you could use the `Node.viewOrder` property instead, if you want. To change based on focus, listen to the `Node.focused` property.

Comment: Sorry for the misundertanding. I am able to change the render order of the elements inside the stackpane but I'm not able to move them horizontically or vertically (which I need for the overlap) without placeholders. And placeholders make the lower layers unclickable.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] please? There may be a better way to do what you want, but without seeing what you've tried and what you're goals are exactly it's difficult to provide a possible solution.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673292/internal-frames-in-javafx

Comment: Do not use a layout that sets the child positions. `Pane` does not adjust `layoutX` and `layoutY` and can be used in comination with `toFront` to achieve the desired results...